# Scrape table from HTML with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a [website](http://paladins.guru/profile/pc/Encrytedbro/champions) with python3. The website contains data on players from a champion based FPS multiplayer game named "Paladins". I wanted to get the champion based stats of a player as shown in the website. The problem I'm facing is, when I inspect the page source with Chrome, I get this code which contains "table" tag and is clean and I could scrape it easily:

[INSPECTED CODE](https://gist.github.com/AkibSadmanee/3a728a168c5d35bb3e239186610d7795) (my gist link)

but when I make the soup object, I get a different code. and when I went over to the page source, it was the same as the soup. there was no  tag there in the page source. (you may check the page source for a better understanding).

Now how may I scrape champion-wise data from the website?
I am using requests and beautifulsoup for python3

```
import requests as req
import bs4
res = req.get('http://paladins.guru/profile/pc/Encrytedbro/champions')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
soup.select('#root')
```

It is giving me this result: [HERE'S A LINK TO MY GIST](https://gist.github.com/AkibSadmanee/0d9d9bc42c73e1cf393753db4e049aef) 
And i have no idea how to get the data out of there.

Comment: it's just that the page is dynamically generated. you should use something like selenium

Answer (score -2):

I think you're getting error because you are using wrong parser, you should use `html.parser` instead of `lxml`

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
```

hope this solves the problem

Comment: do you know the difference? I'm scraping a table with `lxml`

Comment: please view the thread for difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714417/beautiful-soup-and-table-scraping-lxml-vs-html-parser