# Scraping Amazon products names

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to gather the first two pages products names on Amazon based on seller name. When I request the page, it has all elements I need ,however, when I use `BeautifulSoup` - they are not being listed. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
res = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?me=A3WE363L17WQR&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER", headers=headers)
#print(res.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
soup.find_all("a",href=True)
```

The links of products are not listed. If the Amazon API gives this information, I am open to use it (please provide some examples of its usage). Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some detail on what you are seeing and what you expected to see?

Comment: they may be dynamically loaded and require a method like selenium

Comment: @QHarr that is what i thought at the beginning but they are present in in `res.text` which is weird! however not present in soup

Comment: @EliotK what i want is to get the products titles(names) which are present in `res.text` as stated in question but not in soup

Comment: E.g. would be Dr. Elsey's Cat Ultra Premium Clumping Cat Litter (Pack May Vary)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extracted product names from alt attribute. Is this as intended?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s?me=A3WE363L17WQR&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
items = [item['alt'] for item in soup.select('.a-link-normal [alt]')]
print(items)
```

Over two pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?i=merchant-items&me=A3WE363L17WQR&page={}&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&qid=1553116056&ref=sr_pg_{}'
for page in range(1,3):
    r = requests.get(url.format(page,page))
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    items = [item['alt'] for item in soup.select('.a-link-normal [alt]')]
    print(items)
```

Comment: i have solved this problem using `lxml.html' module but i wonder why soup(html) couldn't read it

Comment: so the above worked as expected? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714417/beautiful-soup-and-table-scraping-lxml-vs-html-parser   lxml I think is possibly better with poorly formed html.