# BeatifulSoup and requests returning "None"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im new to bs4 and requests and I'm trying to webscrape Amazon for the price of some random product (in this case an eco dot 3). I dont understand why my web scraper always returns "None" when I run it. Clearly the element I am looking for is present, but still when I try and use the find function it doesnt work.
I dont know if it helps but here is the tutorial I was following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY&t=594sThank you very much! Also here's my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07NQCVHQ6/ref=gw_de_desk_h1_aucc_db_dbckpscs_qh_0520_v1_t1?pf_rd_r=WY9A7Y14N1T2NGG5KT9S&pf_rd_p=56ce1aab-22bc-4377-bb24-b13391bb0efd'
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")
print(price)
```

I dont know if it helps but here is the tutorial I was following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY&t=594s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make simple changes
just change this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
```

output:

```
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString" id="priceblock_ourprice">48,73 ?</span>
```

And:

```
print(price.text)
```

Will give you only the price

about the difference between parsers, you can read on official page - - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers

or in this question, there is explanation - [Beautiful Soup and Table Scraping - lxml vs html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714417/beautiful-soup-and-table-scraping-lxml-vs-html-parser)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.