# Web-scraping with beautifulsoup returns empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Could you please help me to get the name of the products?

You can see the path on the picture [image].

Here the name of product is `Samsung Galaxy....` and other codes

#### What I tried

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests # Import the library for sending requests to the server
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # Import the library for webpage parsing

URL='https://www.amazon.com/s?k=samsung+tablet&crid=3VMSMTMZYOP78&sprefix=samsung+%2Caps%2C273&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_2_8'
req = requests.get(URL) # GET-request

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class_':'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal'})
```

#### Issues

I get an empty list.
I do not understand why this is the case.

Comment: Please format your code-blocks properly, so everyone can quickly read and help. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714417/beautiful-soup-and-table-scraping-lxml-vs-html-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these it will work :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
products=[]
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
}
for page in range(1, 5):
    cookies = {'session': '17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558'}
    r = requests.get(
        "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=samsung+tablet&crid=3VMSMTMZYOP78&sprefix=samsung+%2Caps%2C273&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_2_8={page}".format(
            page=page
        ),
        headers=headers,
        cookies =cookies
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    for d in soup.select(".s-result-item[data-component-type='s-search-result']"):
        name=d.find('h2')
        if name is not None:
            products.append(name.text)
        else:
            products.append("-")

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products})
print(df)
```

0

output:

```
                                        Product Name
0   SAMSUNG Galaxy Tab S7 FE 2021 Android Tablet 1...
1   Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 10.4 Wi-Fi 32GB Silver (...
2   Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 10.4 Wi-Fi 32GB Silver (...
3   Samsung Tab A7 Lite 8.7" Gray 32GB (SM-T220NZA...
4   SAMSUNG Galaxy Tab A 8.0-inch Android Tablet 6...
..                                                ...
83  2020 Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 10.4�� (2000x1200) ...
84  Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite 10.4�� Touchscreen ...
85  Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite 10.4", 64GB Wi-Fi T...
86  SAMSUNG Galaxy Tab S7 11-inch Android Tablet 1...
87  SAMSUNG Galaxy S20 FE 5G Factory Unlocked Andr...
```

Comment: choose `class_=h2` tag instead of  `class_=a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal`

Comment: You `try` these code??

Answer (score 1):

You should probably adjust your `URL` for scraping.

#### Test using curl

When I run a curl request using this URL, the responded HTML does not contain the expected `<span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">`.

```sh
curl 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=samsung+tablet&crid=3VMSMTMZYOP78&sprefix=samsung+%2Caps%2C273&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_2_8' | grep "<span class="
```

But only following spans:

```
                                    <span class="a-button a-button-primary a-span12">
                                        <span class="a-button-inner">
            <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
            <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
            <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
            <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
```

#### Test the soup

You can also test the `soup` as [HedgeHog commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273087/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup-returns-empty-list/69273381#comment122438779_69273087):

```py
import requests # Import the library for sending requests to the server
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # Import the library for webpage parsing

url ='https://www.amazon.com/s?k=samsung+tablet&crid=3VMSMTMZYOP78&sprefix=samsung+%2Caps%2C273&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_2_8'
response = requests.get(url) # GET-request

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html')  # adjusted from lxml to html
print(soup) # contains span elements but not expected

elements = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class_':'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal'})
print(elements) # empty list, the expected spans were not found
```

You will discover a robot-prevention, probably using a captcha to verify a human is using a browser:

```html
<h4>Enter the characters you see below</h4>
<p class="a-last">Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies.</p>
```

**Fun fact**:
You can copy & paste or write the resulting HTML to a file and open in your browser. It shows the guarding dogs of Amazon:
[image: a dog picture indicating an error at Amazon]

See also [All The Dogs You Can Meet If You're Trying To Get On Amazon But It's Broken](https://www.buzzfeed.com/lyapalater/all-the-dogs-you-can-meet-if-youre-trying-to-get-on-amazon)

#### Workaround: passing required request-headers

Further research suggested to add 2 headers to the request (that your browser automatically adds, too):

- a valid `User-Agent` (can simulate a specific browser and OS/platform)
- the `Accept-Language` (is required by most e-commerce pages to localize content)

In *requests* you can add them as dictionary like:

```py
HEADERS = ({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'
})
  
response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
```

See:

- GeeksforGeeks (2020): [Scraping Amazon Product Information using Beautiful Soup](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scraping-amazon-product-information-using-beautiful-soup/)